# ffmpeg printing unknown glyph between characters on utf-8 subtitle

Tags: ffmpeg, character-encoding, utf-8, handbrake

FFmpeg is printing unknown glyphs between some two characters but the weird thing is it's not replacing a character that doesn't exist in the font, it's just printing a new unknown glygh and I can't understand why.

```
x=src.mkv
y=src.srt
format=mkv
out=out
mkdir $out
speak=ffmpeg finished
params="-preset fast -crf 25"
ffmpeg -i "$x" -to 00:15:35 $params -vf "subtitles=$y" $out/1.$format ; espeak "$speak"
```

[image]

The srt file is encoded in utf-8. But I tried specifying the subtitle encoding and also a different font for FFmpeg to no avail:

```
ffmpeg -i "$x" -to 00:15:35 $params -vf "subtitles=$y:force_style='FontName=B Nazanin':charenc='utf-8'" $out/1.$format ; espeak "$speak"
```

Last thing I could think of trying, was to convert the `.srt` subtitle to `.ass` format but it also didn't help.

I'm using the latest FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg version 6.0-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
```

I tried burning in the subtitles using HandBrake instead, with the `.ass` subtitle, just to see if it prints the unknown glyph and it didn't! I should also note that it's a very old version (1.1.1 2018061800) and HandBrake is most likely using FFmpeg internally I thought, so there should be a parameter that HandBrake is using that prevents this issue.
[image]

This is an example of the subtitle line that FFmpeg prints unknown glyphs for:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:01:00,000
‫اگه بتونم کلانتر رو قانع کنم...
```

To reproduce the issue you can follow these:

Create a subtitle file called `sub.srt` and paste the subtitle line above in the file.

Make a still image with Imagemagick:

```
convert -size 1280x720 xc:gray +noise gaussian jpg: | convert -define jpeg:extent=400kb - image.jpg
```

Now with this command, burn in the subtitle on a new video:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest -preset fast -crf 25 -vf "subtitles=sub.srt" -to 00:01:00 out.mp4
```

Comment: In Unicode some characters can have several representations. Thus, encoded in UTF8, these characters are written in 2 or 3 bytes. It may be the third byte that becomes parasitic in your subtitle. Try to normalize your UTF8 characters using for example uconv (from [ICU project](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu)). Example command: `uconv -x Any-NFC -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 -o sub_fix.ass sub.ass`